# Stop watch java script without using Date.getTime()

Tags: javascript, stopwatch

As a java script beginner, I wanted to try my hand at writing stop watch code and I wrote the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p>A script on this page starts a stopwatch:</p>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <button id="start-stop" onclick="myTimerFunction()">Start time</button>
    <button id="resetter" style="visibility:hidden" onclick="resetTimer()">Reset</button>

    <script>
        var timer = new Object();
        timer.hours = 0;
        timer.minutes = 0;
        timer.seconds = 0;
        timer.milliseconds = 0;
        timer.add = add;
        function add() {
            timer.milliseconds+=10;
            if(timer.milliseconds == 1000) {
                timer.seconds++;
                timer.milliseconds = 0;
            }
            if(timer.seconds == 60) {
                timer.minutes++;
                timer.seconds = 0;
            }
            if(timer.minutes == 60) {
                timer.hours++;
                timer.minutes = 0;
            }
        }
        timer.display = display;
        function display () {
            var str = "";
            if(timer.hours<10) {
                str += "0";
            }
            str += timer.hours;
            str += ":";
            if(timer.minutes<10) {
                str += "0";
            }
            str += timer.minutes;
            str += ":";
            if(timer.seconds<10) {
                str += "0";
            }
            str += timer.seconds;
            str += ":";
            /*var x = timer.milliseconds/10;
            if(x < 10) {
                str += "0";
            }*/
            if(timer.milliseconds<10) {
                str += "0";
            }
            if(timer.milliseconds<100) {
                str += "0";
            }
            str += timer.milliseconds;
            return str;
        }
        timer.reset = reset;
        function reset() {
            timer.hours = 0;
            timer.minutes = 0;
            timer.seconds = 0;
            timer.milliseconds = 0;
        }

        var myVar;
        function start() {
            timer.add();
            var d = new Date();
            var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = timer.display() + "\t" + t;
        }

        function stop() {
            clearInterval(myVar);
        }

        function resetTimer() {
            stop();
            timer.reset();
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = timer.display();
            document.getElementById("start-stop").innerHTML="Start time";
            document.getElementById("resetter").style.visibility="hidden";
        }

        function myTimerFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("start-stop");
            if(x.innerHTML.match("Start time")) {
                document.getElementById("resetter").style.visibility="visible";
                myVar = setInterval(function(){start()},10);
                x.innerHTML="Stop time";
            }
            else if(x.innerHTML.match("Stop time")) {
                stop();
                x.innerHTML="Start time";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But, the problem is when I put the ***delay*** in ***setInterval(func,delay)*** as **1** and doing corresponding changes, it is not giving reliable timing for seconds. It is slower than a normal clock. It gives 'kind of' reliable timing for *delay >= 10*.

I checked for stop watch js scripts online but all of them use some or other form of Date() and set "delay" as "50", which I do not understand why, as of now. There is an answer here in SO which doesn't use Date() but it also has the same problem as mine. I could not comment there as I do not have enough reputation so I am asking a question instead.

So, my question is: Is it impossible to achive normal clock reliability, if we don't use Date() function? Else if it is possible, please help me improve this piece of code or please provide some pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: And you'd want to avoid `getTime` because?

Comment: I felt that I am relying on an already available counter. Since I am implementing a counter, I felt that it is not what I am supposed to choose but some other way. But, now I feel like I am re-implementing the wheel.

Comment: My answer below provides an example of what you're trying when you click on Fiddle. `getTime` is more appropriate/accurate for longer durations.

Comment: Yeah, it seems so. I should have done more research. Thanks for the inputs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found out `setInterval/setTimeout` is not reliable. You *must* use a native time library to get a reliable time.

Since you can't keep the time in JavaScript the idea is that you poll the time, and poll it often so that it looks close enough.

If you naively do:

```
setInterval(function () {
    console.log((new Date()).getTime();
}, 1000); // 1 second
```

you will see that it will skip seconds.

A better approach is something like:

```
var last = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    var now = Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000); // now in seconds
    if (now !== last) {
        console.log(now);
        last = now;
    }
}, 10); // 10ms
```

Comment: Why would you `Math.floor` seconds every 10 ms?

Comment: I suppose you could do `if (last >= now - 1) {` instead. That's probably better.

Comment: @Doge I think it should be `if (last <= now - 1)` since _last_ is _0_ when _now_ is some large number.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you'd do it without `getTime`, which you really shouldn't...

```
var ms = 0;
var intervalID;

function start() {
    var freq = 10; // ms
    intervalID = setInterval(function () {
        ms += 10;
        var myDate = new Date(ms);
        document.getElementById('watch').innerHTML = myDate.getUTCHours() + ":" + myDate.getMinutes() + ":" + myDate.getSeconds() +
            ":" + myDate.getMilliseconds();
    }, freq);
}

function stop() {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
}

function reset() {
    ms = 0;
    myDate = new Date(ms);
    document.getElementById('watch').innerHTML = myDate.getUTCHours() + ":" + myDate.getMinutes() + ":" + myDate.getSeconds() +
        ":" + myDate.getMilliseconds();
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/P28c3/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want more information as too why JavaScript timers are unreliable, read this great article.

http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: Thanks, it was a nice read. Now, I understand that I should not rely too much on "delay"s of setInterval, but that I should give it sufficient time to recover.